# react download on click with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, download

I have a react app and I want to download a file via a predefined link as soon as I click on download bottom.
The issue is that it starts downloading without clicking on download bottom whenever I refresh.

here is how I defined bottom:

```
 <div className="file-list">
      <ul className="m-0 p-0 px-3 pt-1">
        {filesList.map((value) => (
          <li key={value} className="file-item p-2 mb-2">
            <div className="is-flex is-align-items-center">
              <img className="fileIcon mr-3" src={FileIcon} />
              <span className="filename is-flex">{value}</span>
              <div className="is-flex is-flex-direction-column is-align-items-center">
                <Icon
                  onClick={downloadSampleCsvFile(value)}
                  path={mdiDownload}
                  title="Download"
                  size={0.79}
                  color="#0a85c7"
                />
```

here is how I defined downloadSampleCsvFile(value):

```
const downloadSampleCsvFile = (v) => {

    axios({
      url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anubhav-goel/react-download-file-axios/main/sampleFiles/csv-sample.csv', //your url
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'blob', // important
  }).then((response) => {
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute('download', 'csv-sample.csv'); //or any other extension
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
  });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file gets downloaded automatically because you're invoking download function in `onChange` event listener . Simply change it to this

```
onClick={() => downloadSampleCsvFile(value)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is running as soon as the element is rendered since you are calling it directly. A better way to do it is

```
()=>downloadSampleCsvFile(value)
```